# Neo4j - Is the package org.neo4j.graphdb.index thread safe?

Tags: java, lucene, neo4j

I couldn't understand from the Neo4j documentation whether the org.neo4j.graphdb.index package implementation is thread safe, that is, can I safely access the same `Index<Node>` object from two different threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some [older posts](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/neo4j/index%2420thread%2420safe/neo4j/VBopmG_dJ4c/AsDtHU4jNq8J), but yes, it's thread safe. You should be able to get one instance of it and pass around on threads.